# Max TPS for strongly consistent reads on an on-demand dynamo db table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a use case where I need to handle 3000 TPS of incoming traffic. This would mainly involve calling a DynamoDB table to do version checks.

We plan to have an on-demand table for this. Wanted to understand whether there is some upper limit on the TPS that DynamoDB can handle here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper limit if your access patterns are well distributed. A single partition can handle 3000RCU per second, that essentially translates to 3000RCU per item. If you are well distributed and accessing multiple items then you will not encounter any issue.